# stop scroll to top after add to cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have found posts about stopping scroll to the top after a click, but I could not understand how to implement this in my particular code.

When the user clicks on the 'add to cart' button, the page scrolls to the top of the page. I am using code to allow customers to add variable quantities from the shop page in woocommerce.

I want to stop the on click behaviour from scrolling to the top of the page.

Here is the code for add-to-cart.php

```
<?php
/**
* Custom Loop Add to Cart.
* 
* Template with quantity.
*
* @author      WooThemes
* @package     WooCommerce/Templates
* @version     1.6.4
*/
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
global $product;
?>

<?php if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) : ?>

<a href="<?php echo apply_filters( 'out_of_stock_add_to_cart_url',      get_permalink( $product->id ) ); ?>" class="button"><?php echo apply_filters( 'out_of_stock_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Read More', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?></a>

<?php else : ?>

<?php
    $link = array(
        'url'   => '',
        'label' => '',
        'class' => ''
    );
    switch ( $product->product_type ) {
        case "variable" :
            $link['url']    = apply_filters(   'variable_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
            $link['label']  = apply_filters(  'variable_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Select options', 'woocommerce' ) );
        break;
        case "grouped" :
            $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'grouped_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
            $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'grouped_add_to_cart_text', __( 'View options', 'woocommerce' ) );
        break;
        case "external" :
            $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'external_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
            $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'external_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Read More', 'woocommerce' ) );
        break;
        default :
            if ( $product->is_purchasable() ) {
                $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'add_to_cart_url', esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) );
                $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'add_to_cart_text', __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' ) );
                $link['class']  = apply_filters( 'add_to_cart_class', 'add_to_cart_button' );
            } else {
                $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'not_purchasable_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
                $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'not_purchasable_text', __( 'Read More', 'woocommerce' ) );
            }
        break;
    }
    // If there is a simple product.
    if ( $product->product_type == 'simple' ) {
        ?>
        <form action="<?php echo esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <?php
                // Displays the quantity box.
                woocommerce_quantity_input();
            ?>
            <button type="submit" class="button alt"><?php echo $link['label']; ?></button>
        </form>
        <?php
    } else {
      echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', sprintf('<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s button product_type_%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $link['url'] ), esc_attr( $product->id ), esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ), esc_attr( $link['class'] ), esc_attr( $product->product_type ), esc_html( $link['label'] ) ), $product, $link );
    }
?>
```

And this is the code in the functions.php

```
/* Add variable add to cart button */
function cs_wc_loop_add_to_cart_scripts() {
if ( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ||  is_product() ) : ?>


<script>
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $( document ).on( 'change', '.quantity .qty', function() {
        $( this ).parent( '.quantity' ).next( '.add_to_cart_button'  ).data( 'quantity', $( this ).val() );
    });
});
</script>


<?php endif;
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cs_wc_loop_add_to_cart_scripts' );


/**
* start the customisation
*/
function custom_woo_before_shop_link() {
add_filter('woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',  'custom_woo_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2);
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop',  'custom_woo_after_shop_loop');
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop',   'custom_woo_before_shop_link');
/**
* customise Add to Cart link/button for product loop
* @param string $button
* @param object $product
* @return string
*/
function custom_woo_loop_add_to_cart_link($button, $product) {
// not for variable, grouped or external products
if (!in_array($product->product_type, array('variable', 'grouped',  'external'))) {
    // only if can be purchased
    if ($product->is_purchasable()) {
        // show qty +/- with button
        ob_start();
        woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart();
        $button = ob_get_clean();
        // modify button so that AJAX add-to-cart script finds it
        $replacement = sprintf('data-product_id="%d" data-quantity="1" $1 ajax_add_to_cart add_to_cart_button product_type_simple ', $product->id);
        $button = preg_replace('/(class="single_add_to_cart_button)/', $replacement, $button);
    }
}
return $button;
}
/**
* add the required JavaScript
*/
function custom_woo_after_shop_loop() {
?>


<script>
jQuery(function($) {
<?php /* when product quantity changes, update quantity attribute on  add-to-cart button */ ?>
$("form.cart").on("change", "input.qty", function() {
    $(this.form).find("button[data-quantity]").data("quantity", this.value);
});
<?php /* remove old "view cart" text, only need latest one thanks! */ ?>
$(document.body).on("adding_to_cart", function() {
    $("a.added_to_cart").remove();
});
});
</script>


<?php
}
```

Here is the AJAX add to cart script

```
/**
 * AJAX add to cart.
 */
public static function add_to_cart() {
    ob_start();

    $product_id        = apply_filters(  'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint( $_POST['product_id'] ) );
    $quantity          = empty( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? 1 :  wc_stock_amount( $_POST['quantity'] );
    $passed_validation = apply_filters(  'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity );
    $product_status    = get_post_status( $product_id );

    if ( $passed_validation && false !== WC()->cart->add_to_cart(  $product_id, $quantity ) && 'publish' === $product_status ) {

        do_action( 'woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product_id );

        if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) == 'yes' ) {
            wc_add_to_cart_message( array( $product_id => $quantity ), true );
        }

        // Return fragments
        self::get_refreshed_fragments();

    } else {

        // If there was an error adding to the cart, redirect to the  product page to show any errors
        $data = array(
            'error'       => true,
            'product_url' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', get_permalink( $product_id ), $product_id )
        );

        wp_send_json( $data );

    }

    die();
}
```

This file also references the ajax add to cart. It is the woocommerce add-to-cart.js

```
/*!
* WooCommerce Add to Cart JS
*/
jQuery( function( $ ) {

/* global wc_add_to_cart_params */
if ( typeof wc_add_to_cart_params === 'undefined' ) {
    return false;
}

// Ajax add to cart
$( document ).on( 'click', '.add_to_cart_button', function() {

    // AJAX add to cart request
    var $thisbutton = $( this );

    if ( $thisbutton.is( '.ajax_add_to_cart' ) ) {

        if ( ! $thisbutton.attr( 'data-product_id' ) ) {
            return true;
        }

        $thisbutton.removeClass( 'added' );
        $thisbutton.addClass( 'loading' );

        var data = {};

        $.each( $thisbutton.data(), function( key, value ) {
            data[key] = value;
        });

        // Trigger event
        $( document.body ).trigger( 'adding_to_cart', [ $thisbutton, data ] );

        // Ajax action
        $.post( wc_add_to_cart_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace( '%%endpoint%%', 'add_to_cart' ), data, function( response ) {

            if ( ! response ) {
                return;
            }

            var this_page = window.location.toString();

            this_page = this_page.replace( 'add-to-cart', 'added-to-cart' );

            if ( response.error && response.product_url ) {
                window.location = response.product_url;
                return;
            }

            // Redirect to cart option
            if ( wc_add_to_cart_params.cart_redirect_after_add === 'yes' ) {

                window.location = wc_add_to_cart_params.cart_url;
                return;

            } else {

                $thisbutton.removeClass( 'loading' );

                var fragments = response.fragments;
                var cart_hash = response.cart_hash;

                // Block fragments class
                if ( fragments ) {
                    $.each( fragments, function( key ) {
                        $( key ).addClass( 'updating' );
                    });
                }

                // Block widgets and fragments
                $( '.shop_table.cart, .updating, .cart_totals' ).fadeTo( '400', '0.6' ).block({
                    message: null,
                    overlayCSS: {
                        opacity: 0.6
                    }
                });

                // Changes button classes
                $thisbutton.addClass( 'added' );

                // View cart text
                if ( ! wc_add_to_cart_params.is_cart && $thisbutton.parent().find( '.added_to_cart' ).length === 0 ) {
                    $thisbutton.after( ' <a href="' + wc_add_to_cart_params.cart_url + '" class="added_to_cart wc-forward" title="' +
                        wc_add_to_cart_params.i18n_view_cart + '">' + wc_add_to_cart_params.i18n_view_cart + '</a>' );
                }

                // Replace fragments
                if ( fragments ) {
                    $.each( fragments, function( key, value ) {
                        $( key ).replaceWith( value );
                    });
                }

                // Unblock
                $( '.widget_shopping_cart, .updating' ).stop( true ).css( 'opacity', '1' ).unblock();

                // Cart page elements
                $( '.shop_table.cart' ).load( this_page + ' .shop_table.cart:eq(0) > *', function() {

                    $( '.shop_table.cart' ).stop( true ).css( 'opacity', '1' ).unblock();

                    $( document.body ).trigger( 'cart_page_refreshed' );
                });

                $( '.cart_totals' ).load( this_page + ' .cart_totals:eq(0) > *', function() {
                    $( '.cart_totals' ).stop( true ).css( 'opacity', '1' ).unblock();
                });

                // Trigger event so themes can refresh other areas
                $( document.body ).trigger( 'added_to_cart', [ fragments, cart_hash, $thisbutton ] );
            }
        });

        return false;

    }

    return true;
});
```

});

Thank you in advance if you can help!

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry to say that after reviewing your question I don't have enough information to assist you. Do you have the JavaScript script that's referred to in `functions.php` on this line: `// modify button so that AJAX add-to-cart script finds it`?

If you can find that, add it to your question and then notify me using `@rhono`!

Comment: Hi @rhono I think I have found the AJAX add to cart script. Is this what you mean?  I have also found a woocommerce add to cart js. Let me know if you want me to add that. It is hard to know exactly what you are looking for, without knowing js. Thanks so much!!

Comment: php cannot scroll your page, it has to be in javascript or some other client side method, OR a page reload. Search the javascript for stuff like `window.scroll`, `window.scrollBy`, or different library methods like `.scroll` `.scrollTop`, `.animate` etc. I'm sure you'll be able to find the offending code.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I needed to see!

Answer (score 2):

Override the scroll_to_notices jQuery function. After your woocommerce.js is called you can add :

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {
  $.scroll_to_notices = function( scrollElement ) {
    // Your changes ...
    return;
  };
});
```

This will prevent the scrolling.
In my case the issue was the scroll was wrong due ton fixed header so I just replace return above by:

```
$( 'html, body' ).animate( { scrollTop:0 }, 1000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Catch the button's `click` event and stop it's default behaviour, which includes scrolling to the top of the page.

Inside `add-to-cart.js`:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.add_to_cart_button', function(e) { // <-- 'e' is a jQuery event object

    e.preventDefault(); // This should be all you need :)

    // AJAX add to cart request
    var $thisbutton = $( this );
// ...
}
```

If you're curious about the [jQuery Event Object](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

> The event object is guaranteed to be passed to the event handler.

### Wait a minute

You should be able to achieve the same thing as the whole `e.preventDefault()` by changing the `<button type="submit" ... >` to `<button type="button" ...>`

Comment: Thanks @Rhono, I am still confused though. I don't know Javascript or jQuery. Where do I put this code and how to I put it inside the jQuery document.ready. Sorry for my ignorance. :-) Could you possibly tell me the whole code snippet I need to add to the functions.php?

Comment: @Sarahjames No worries, I'll write a more detailed answer when I get home!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @Rhono. Unfortunately it doesn't work. When I change `<button type="submit"...>` to `<button type="button"...>` it half works - the page does not refresh as you suspected, but the products don't get added to the cart. When I try the jQuery event object, this has no effect. I have tried replacing the code starting with `$( document )` with your code and also adding it in afterwards but nothing seems to work. I do appreciate your help though! Any further thoughts would be welcome!

Comment: The prevent default function will also prevent the product from being added.

Answer (score 0):

This works. Add following code in your js file.

```
var timeout;
 
jQuery( function( $ ) {
        $('.woocommerce').on('change', 'input.qty', function(){

            if ( timeout !== undefined ) {
                clearTimeout( timeout );
            }

            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                $("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click");
                document.location.reload(true);
            });
        });
});
```